# Al ejecutar el codigo en vsc se va a ejecutarlo directamente al output y no en las terminales

Tags: vscode

soy nuevo y estoy aprendiendo node js y no se en que momento todo el codigo con el que estaba practicando se empezo a ejecutar en el output del visual studio code en vez de en las terminales como venia haciendo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Hola probablemente estas usando una extension el cual esta ejecutando el codigo. debe ser un runner.. debes desactivar esa extension.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).